# How do I address this error: vstest.executionengine.x86.exe has stopped working?

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, approval-tests

After adding a new unit test with multiple VS versions running I get this error:

vstest.executionengine.x86.exe has stopped working

in a popup window.

Comment: I just discovered that the partial class's ToString() override had a dependency on another object causing a stack overflow. I replaced the generic PropertiesToString with explicit tostring calls on the properties for the new object.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I had to check for recursive calls to resolve(ToString in foreign key mappings). See comment on question for details.

Comment: Yep, 90% of the time its a Stackoverflow Exception under the hood